# ¿Como hago repito mi codigo sin utilizar variables globales?

Tags: python, self

Tengo que rehacer este codigo sin variables globales... Es una actividad evaluativa de un curso de aprendizaje que estoy tomando en python; el profesor señala que el codigo esta correcto pero que debo de plantearlo sin la necesidad de usar "global" y tampoco creo que permita que use "self" hasta el momento porque apenas es la siguiente tematica objetos. ¿Que recomiendan en este caso para que el codigo me funcione?

Intente plantear el codigo definiendo las variables dentro de la funcion pero luego la siguiente funcion me dice que la variable no existe, no se que hacer en este caso.

Aprecio los consejos, muchas gracias:

```
Archivo= Archivo + ".txt"

def lectura(Archivo):
    lista1= []
    lista2= []
    lista3= []
    lista4= []
    listaconvacios= []
    datos=open(Archivo,'r')

    datos.readline()
    while True:
        lineas=datos.readline()
        if "nan" in lineas:
            listaconvacios.append(lineas)
            if lineas=='':
                break
        else:
            res=[float(num) for num in lineas.split(';')]
            lista1.append(res[0])
            lista2.append(res[1])
            lista3.append(res[2])
            lista4.append(res[3])
            return lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4
lectura(Archivo)
#print('datosx', lista1)
#print('datosy', lista2)
#print('datosz', lista3)
#print('datosw', lista4)

#Columna 1 Vs Columna 2

def Grafica1(lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4):
    lista1= lista1
    lista2= lista2
    lista3=lista3
    lista4=lista4
    #Columna 1 vs Columna 2
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")
    plt.ioff()
    plt.plot(lista2)
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista2)
    plt.plot(lista1, label = "Confirmados")
    plt.plot(lista2, label = "Activos")
    plt.legend()

    #Columna 1 vs Columna 3
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")  
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")  
    plt.ioff() 
    plt.plot(lista3) 
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista3)
    plt.plot(lista3, label = "Recuperados")
    plt.legend()

    #Columna 1 vs Columna 4
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")  
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")  
    plt.ioff() 
    plt.plot(lista4) 
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista4)
    plt.plot(lista4, label = "Muertos")
    plt.legend() 


def Grafica2(lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4):

    #Columna 1 vs Columna 2
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")
    plt.ioff()
    plt.plot(lista2)
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista2)
    plt.plot(lista1, label = "Confirmados")
    plt.plot(lista2, label = "Activos")
    plt.legend()


    #Columna 1 vs Columna 3
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")  
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")  
    plt.ioff() 
    plt.plot(lista3) 
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista3) 
    plt.plot(lista1, label = "Confirmados")
    plt.plot(lista3, label = "Recuperados")
    plt.legend()


    #Columna 1 vs Columna 4
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(lista1)
    plt.xlabel("Tiempo")  
    plt.ylabel("Cantidad")  
    plt.ioff() 
    plt.plot(lista4) 
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot(lista4) 
    plt.plot(lista1, label = "Confirmados")
    plt.plot(lista4, label = "Muertos")
    plt.legend()


Grafica1(lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4)    

#Grafica2(lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4)
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías eliminar la variable Archivo que estas usando para formar el nombre del archivo que quieres abrir. Mejor cuando quieras abrir el archivo con el método open() escribe directamente el nombre del archivo que quieres abrir. Ejemplo: `datos=open("NOMBRE_DE_TU_ARCHIVO.txt,'r')`